# NAudio: How can I get an event that tells me that the MP3 file reached the end?

Tags: events, mp3, naudio

I tried to use this:

```
private void CreateDevice()
{
    _playbackDevice = new WaveOut();
    _playbackDevice.PlaybackStopped += PlaybackDevicePlaybackStopped;
}

void PlaybackDevicePlaybackStopped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (OnPlaybackStopped != null)
    {
        OnPlaybackStopped(this, e);
    }
}
```

But it never invoked.

Then I tried to use the PlaybackState by polling the property with a timer:

```
public PlaybackState PlaybackState
{
    get
    {
        if (_playbackDevice == null)
            return default(PlaybackState);

        return _playbackDevice.PlaybackState;
    }
}
```

But when the song ends it does not change to "stopped". But when I call manually Stop it changes correctly.

Can someone help me?

There seems to be a bug ... http://naudio.codeplex.com/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=10726

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com) is designed to allow you to do more complicated things than simply playing one file, it will not necessarily stop at the end of a file. What determines whether WaveOut will stop is whether we stop feeding it data or not. Some WaveStreams in NAudio do stop providing data when they have reached the end of a file, but other WaveStreams will happily return buffers full of zeroes from their Read method as many times as they are called. So auto-stopping depends a lot on the graph of WaveStreams you have constructed.

Because of this you may need to determine when to stop by when you have finished reading the contents of the file to be played. I realise this is not an ideal situation, and I am still trying to come up with a design that works well both for those who just want to play a single file, and for those who are doing something a bit more involved.

Comment: Have you come up with a solution? It is a bit awkward if audio keeps playing if I have rewind it from the end. A ReachedEnd event or a boolean StopAtEnd property would be enough. Actually I would prefer pausing over stopping ;)

Comment: What are you playing? If you play a never-ending stream, `PlaybackStopped` will never fire. But if you play a file (e.g. `Mp3FileReader` you'll auto-stop at the end)

Comment: I am playing a wave file using WaveOutEvent and AudioFileReader. It would be a good idea to have also and event which is called when the play state changes (playing, paused, stopped etc).

Comment: You can monitor the session that the stream belongs to.with  RegisterEventClient. It won't tell you when the stream ends, but it will notify you when the state of the stream switches from active to inactive and vice versa.

Comment: where's the code solutions for obtaining that events?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In your CreateDevice method, change this line:

```
_playbackDevice = new WaveOut();
```

by this:

```
_playbackDevice = new WaveOut(WaveCallbackInfo.FunctionCallback()
```

Comment: I don't recommend doing this. Function callbacks often cause deadlocks. Instead use the `WaveOutEvent` class if you are not in a Windows Forms or WPF app.